# How to select the row with the minimum value of a column while the other column is at its maximum?

Tags: mysql, sql, max, min

In SQL, how can I  select the minimum value of a column `a` (integer) where the column `b` (integer) is the maximum value for that column, using only one select ?

```
SELECT MIN(a) OVER (PARTITION BY MAX(b)) as res #seems to be ill-formed
FROM table
```

For instance

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |

should return

| res |
| --- |
| 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`order by` and `limit` should be good enough here:

```
select a
from mytable
order by b desc, a
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a nested SELECT MIN

```
SELECT MIN(a) FROM table WHERE b = (SELECT MIN(b) FROM table);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using windowing functions to avoid a second pass on the table:

```
select min(a)
  from (select a,
               b
               MAX(b) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) max_b
          from table)
  where b = max_b
```